# llvm-link: error : expected top-level entity

Tags: llvm

I'm trying to compile the libpng 1.2.56 file and use a target.cc(same as [fuzzer-test-suite](https://github.com/google/fuzzer-test-suite/tree/master/libpng-1.2.56/target.cc) to unite all these file in libpng1.2.56 into one LLVM IR bitcode file, named combined.bc.

Here is my compile process, refering [build.sh](https://github.com/google/fuzzer-test-suite/blob/master/libpng-1.2.56/build.sh):

```
[ ! -e libpng-1.2.56.tar.gz ] && wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng12/older-releases/1.2.56/libpng-1.2.56.tar.gz
[ ! -e libpng-1.2.56 ] && tar xf libpng-1.2.56.tar.gz

build_lib() {
  rm -rf BUILD
  cp -rf libpng-1.2.56 BUILD
  (cd BUILD && ./configure --disable-shared &&  make -j $JOBS )
}
build_lib || exit 1
mkdir bitcode
clang++-10 -g -flto -std=c++11 ./target.cc -c -o bitcode/target.o -I .
cd bitcode
ar x ../.libs/libpng12.a
llvm-link-10 *.o -o combined.bc
```

And error is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTSiu.png)

The bitcode folder:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qW92o.png)

For modifications like the above, I succeeded on the project json, but not on libpng.
I am a beginner in LLVM and would like to get answers from you all. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It looks to me that your `build.sh` is incomplete, am I right? I do not see where the compiler is set nor where the `-flto` is passed to the libpng build. I'd do sometihng such as `CFLAGS="-flto -fuse-ld=lld" CC=clang-10 ./configure --disable-shared && make -j $JOBS`

Comment: Thanks, I will modify my build.sh and try again today